# C - multiple definition main() K&R eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

***C Programming Language 2nd*** Page 43 example code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int get_line (char line[], int maxline);
void copy (char to[], char from[]);

int main()
{
    int len;
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    max = 0;
    while ((len = get_line(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max)
        {
            max = len;
            copy (longest, line);
        }
   if (max > 0)
        printf("%s", longest);
   return 0;
}

int get_line (char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
    {
        s[i] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
 }
 
void copy (char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

> Info: Internal Builder is used for build
>
> gcc -o HelloWorld.exe "src\HelloWorld.o" "src\test.o"
>
> src\test.o: In function `main':
>
> C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\HelloWorld\Debug/../src/test.c:15: multiple definition of `main'
>
> src\HelloWorld.o:C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\HelloWorld\Debug/../src/HelloWorld.c:14: first defined here
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

***multiple definition of main***

Comment: multiple definition of main

Comment: The error means exactly what it says. Look at `test.c` and `HelloWorld.c`. Do they both have a `main`? If so, that's wrong since you're linking them together. You can only have one `main`. Actually you can only have one of anything that is global. Why are you linking `test` with `HelloWorld`? Does one depend upon the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created two main source files in a single Eclipse project. When these are built, the two main() functions conflict. To resolves this, create seperate empty projects for each set of code you want to build.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to the previous c source file!